# Problems with Delphi Rest Client talking to C# Rest server

Tags: wcf, delphi, rest, delphi-2009

I am writing a REST WCF Service, and have it working for connections from a C# client, but am having issues with connecting via a Delphi 2009 client. The problem I have is specifically with a PUT request, which looks (for the moment) as below. It expects an XML request, containing the document's objects.

```
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "Document/{id}", Method = "PUT", RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    public void UpdateDocument (string id, Document document)
    {
        Document doc = document;

        // this should update or something!
        Console.WriteLine(doc.Id);
    }
```

When I try and call this via my Delphi client (as shown below), I get a 'Bad Request'. Oddly if I send an empty document, the request is received, but obviously has no data.

```
   ...

     msg := '<?xml version="1.0"?>' +
    '<Document>' +
    '<Id>123456788888</Id>' +
    '</Document>';

  XMLDocument1.LoadFromXML(msg);
  xmlStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  idHttp1.Request.ContentType := 'application/xml';
  XMLDocument1.SaveToStream(xmlStream);
  url := 'http://localhost:50435/service1/Document/12345678';
  result := idHttp1.Put(url, xmlStream);
  ShowMessage (result);

  ...
```

Any ideas, as I am a bit lost now!

Thanks

Comment: You can use a HTTP proxy like Fiddler to capture the working and non-working requests and then compare them

Comment: Installing Fiddler helped, but only because I couldn't get it to work, so I looked at the page that the service creates and bingo - I need the namespace to get to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment above, installing Fiddler made me look at the actual page that the webservice outputs, this helpfully has example XML and json structures. I was missing the namespace for the object, so I guess the WCF end didn't know what to translate, changing the message to the following made it work:

```
msg := '<?xml version="1.0"?>' +
'<Document xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Contracts.Contracts">' +
'<Id>123456788888</Id>' +
'</Document>';
```

Comment: this nicely illustrates that [REST is a style of software architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), not a specification ("styles" are not standardized)

Answer (score 0):

The mapping of the URI to server method is not correct. According to default mapping a PUT request will invoke AcceptDocument method, and a POST request will invoke UpdateDocument method.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/REST

Also passing a TStream as parameter is also possibility for difficulties. Is it possible for you to use JSON? I am not sure Delphi 2009 has support for JSON though.

Edit:
quote from Delphi [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/DataSnap_REST_Messaging_Protocol):

> by default, a prefix of 'update' is assigned to any method invoked
>   with POST. Similarly, a prefix of 'cancel' is used for DELETE
>   requests, and a prefix of 'accept' is used for PUT requests. This
>   prefixing can be avoided by putting quotation marks around the method
>   name

Above quote applies to Delphi. Maybe also for WCF.

Comment: The docwiki page is for DataSnap. The code in the question uses a simple Indy IdHTTP component with the URL given by the WCF side, no DataSnap.

Comment: JSON support comes in D2010 unfortunately. This is also 'raw' connections, not using DataSnap

Comment: The mapping of URI to server method happens on server-side. The server is WCF service, and I assume default mapping is used there as described in docwiki page. I am not that familiar with WCF, but I assume in default situation Delphi REST server provides same mapping protocol as WCF service. Anyway, maybe try not to rely on automatic mapping of URI to server methods and specify exact url. And try to pass parameter as string instead of TStream. Hope that helps. My 2 cents.

Comment: [REST is a style of software architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), not a specification